# Get duplicate character in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

How to get duplicate character in JavaScript,

As like input:

`aaabcccdeffa`

Output:

`a4bc3def2`

Comment: What have you tried ? What kind of input ? A string, an array, an text box ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get help you should provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This helps everyone else understand what you are trying to do, and shows us what you have already tried.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var str = "aaabcccdeffa"; // Original string

// We are going to create a key-value array to store the number of occurance
// per letter (eg. 'a' : 4, 'b' : 1 etc.)
var store = {};

// Next we loop through each letter in the string
for (var a in str) {
    if (store[str[a]] == undefined) { // If this letter has not ben found before, we set the count to 1 (first occurance)
    store[str[a]] = 1;
  }
  else { // else if the letter has been found, we increase the count by one 
    store[str[a]] += 1;
  }
}

// At this point, we have a key value array that contains the count of each letter

// Next, we loop through this array to generate the new string
var newStr = ''; // Initialise new string
for (var char in store) {
    newStr += char; // append the letter to the string
  if (store[char] > 1) {
    newStr += store[char]; // If the count is more than one, we want to show the number too, so we append the number to the string
  }
}
```

Output will be in newStr

Answer (score 2):

you can use a HashTable, which in javascript is done through an Object. This code works

```
function duplicateCharacters(str) {
    //Create an empty object
    var hashTable = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        //Check if the character has already been registered
        //If false, register it and link a 1 to it
        //If true, increment the integer linked to it
        if (hashTable.hasOwnProperty(str[i]))
            hashTable[str[i].toString()]++; 
        else
            hashTable[str[i].toString()] = 1;
    }
    var output = "";
    //Go through the hashTable
    for(var key in hashTable) {
        //Concatenate the key
        output += key.toString();
        //If the character only appeared once, do not add it
        if(hashTable[key] != 1)
            output += hashTable[key].toString()
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the reference code which uses both jquery and Regular expression for calculating the frequency of the character.

```
// Variable Declaration with Source text
var sourceText="aaabcccdeffa";
var resultText="";
// Splitting the source text to array
var sourceTextArray=sourceText.split("");
var uniqueText = [];
//Fetches Unique text from sourceTextArray in order
$.each(sourceTextArray, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueText) === -1) uniqueText.push(el);
});
//Iteration with unique text array 
$.each(uniqueText, function(i, el){
//Regular Expression approach to calculate frequency of character with source text
resultText+=(sourceText.match(new RegExp(el, "g")) || []).length>1?el+(sourceText.match(new RegExp(el, "g")) || []).length:el;
});

alert(resultText);
```

[**Working Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/pwdzz52n/3/)